# Pointer to Array of Pointers where each Pointer points to Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

I'm having trouble in C with creating a pointer that points to an array of pointers where each pointer in the array points to an array. I'm having trouble setting this up and storing values in each array. The goal is to avoid array indexing and use pointer arithmetic only. An example of how to implement this idea correctly and storing the values for access later would help me greatly to understand pointers to functions, pointers to arrays, and pointer arithmetic. I do know how to use malloc and calloc. I know basic pointers but this problem is more advanced so some examples of how this is implemented would help greatly! Thanks! :)

Comment: It would be great to show what you have tried. Further, you specified an incomplete type; we need to know what type the innermost arrays store. Also, there's more detail needed -- are the arrays (at each level) fixed size or variable size? etc

Comment: When you say "points to an array", do you actually mean that? (as opposed to "points to the first element of an array"

Comment: You must take care and not confuse an `type *[]` (array of pointers to type) and `type (*)[]` (a pointer to an array).

Comment: An example of type is double

double **overall;
double *point;
int size;

printf("Enter  a number");
scanf("%i", &size);

I just need to know how to use a double pointer (double **pointer) that will point to an array of double pointers (double *point) where each double pointer in the array points to an array of type double and store values but only pointer arithmetic is allow to store values in each array and to access the elements. no Array indexing is allowed so its more complicated

Comment: I know keeping track of the global size is important due to seg faults but how do I incorporate this into the situation?

Comment: The index-operator **is** pointer arithmetic! You cannot index an array in C. You always work on a pointer!

Comment: A[i] that is illegal for this but *(point+i) is okay

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds as if you need something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // Make some arrays of ints
    int a0[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    int a1[3] = {4, 5, 6};

    // To access element a1[2] do *(a1 + 2)
    printf("%d\n", *(a1 + 2));

    // Make an array of int pointers
    int* b[2] = {a0, a1};              // Or:  int* b[2];
                                       //      *(b + 0) = a0;
                                       //      *(b + 1) = a1;

    // To access element a1 do *(b + 1)
    // To access a1[1] through b just combine the two expressions
    // so that you have *(*(b + 1) + 2)
    printf("%d\n", *(*(b + 1) + 2));

    return 0;
}
```

In general: To access `b[i][j]` do `*(*(b + i) + j)`

Comment: so adding elements to the array without using '[]' can be done with just *(b+i)?

Comment: @MD_90 - yes. Instead of the initializer list I could have done it like: `*(b+0) = a0; *(b+1) = a1;`